# Latex problems upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

Here's what I get when I run `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and running `-f` doesn't do anything:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 asymptote : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not installed
             Depends: texlive-base-bin
 latex-beamer : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not installed
 libboost-dev : Depends: libboost1.54-dev but it is not installable
 libboost-serialization-dev : Depends: libboost-serialization1.54-dev but it is not installable
 lilypond-data : Depends: texlive-base-bin
 luatex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2014) but it is not installed
 prosper : Depends: texlive-latex-base but it is not installed
 texlive-base : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not installed
 texlive-latex-extra : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not installed
 texlive-latex-extra-doc : Depends: tex-common (>= 6) but 4.04 is installed
                           Depends: texlive-base (>= 2015) but 2013.20140215-1 is installed
 texlive-latex-recommended : Depends: texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not installed
                             Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not installed
 texlive-luatex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not installed
 texlive-pictures : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not installed
 texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-generic-recommended (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not installed
                    Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2013.20130512) but it is not installed
                    Recommends: texlive-font-utils but it is not installed
                    Recommends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information by referring to this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121181

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error more closely. You need to use

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to resolve any unmet dependencies. So try this then upgrade to 16.04.